# Generate a report using DFSORT

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl, dfsort

I have a task to write a JCL job invoking ICETOOL/DFSORT to generate a report. The report takes a VSAM KSDS as input and generates a list of bank branches.

Each record in the BRANCHES KSDS is of the form

• 4-byte binary unsigned integer representing a 6-digit decimal branch sortcode (e.g. 420101)

• 1-byte EBCDIC flag: ◦ EBCDIC 'A' means the branch is owned by ZeusBank and all its accounts are held in the ACCOUNTS KSDS

◦ EBCDIC 'B' means the branch is not owned by ZeusBank so we do not hold its account information in the ACCOUNTS KSDS

• 32-byte EBCDIC character branch name (e.g. “ZEUSBANK FOOFORD BAR STREET” or “OTHERBANK QUUXHAM BAZ ROAD”), blank padded on the right.

The report should look like this

[image]

I'm pretty new to JCL so please forgive if the question is simple. Thanks.

Comment: Is the report sorted on 1 byte flag? Do you want header only once or should it be repeated after a set of records?

Comment: This link should help you, if you need more help then let me know: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.iceg200/ice2cg_Headers.htm

Comment: Yeah I want it's once only, I have come across the headers thing but there's an error which stop me from doing anything [https://ibb.co/kNy0tR]. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the error? I Can't see the link.

Comment: My report looks like this [https://pastebin.com/gQS9ZEBr]. And I got the error, `O. MESSAGE                                         
 1 HASP105 EXPECTED CONTINUATION NOT RECEIVED      
 1 IEFC621I EXPECTED CONTINUATION NOT RECEIVED     
 2 IEFC662I INVALID LABEL                          
 2 IEFC605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD`. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use ICETOOL. Use Pgm=Sort and then use OUTFIL HEADER2. The error you are getting is because of '-' at the end of each statement. I'll post answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Anyway, I tried to review the VSAM file provided but I can't. It says `VSAM processing unavail`. Is there any way I can view the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159249/discussion-between-tri-nguyen-and-user6542823).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
//STEPSORT EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SORTIN DD DSN=DATASETNAME
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN DD *
SORT FIELDS=(5,1,CH,A)
OUTFIL HEADER2=(1:C'LIST OF WHATEVER BANK',4/,
1:C'SORTCODE',10:C'FLAG',15:C'BRANCH',/,
1:C'--------',10:C'----',15:C'------'),
BUILD=(1:1,4,BI,TO=ZD,LENGTH=6,10:5,1,15:6,32)
/*
```

Comment: Thanks man. However it says `DEFINE - INSUFFICIENT AUTHORITY                                        
 STMT NO. MESSAGE                                                        
-                                                                        
        5 IGD308I DATA SET ALLOCATION REQUEST FAILED -                   
 RACF FUNCTION: RACDEF FOR                                               
 DATA SET: SHECICS.ZEUSBANK.BRANCHES WITH RETURN CODE 08 REASON CODE 00`

Comment: May I ask some questions in chat anyway?

Comment: When I add `DISP=SHR`, I got the error `IEFC621I EXPECTED CONTINUATION NOT RECEIVED`. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I am not free at the moment, will be back after 2 hours. I'll need to see your Job.

Comment: Done it, it was my fault leaving a space after a comma. Thanks. How can I sort the `sortcode` number (which is the first column).

Comment: I change to `SORT FIELD(1,6,ZD,A)` because it's binary format but I still got this [https://ibb.co/iBHfTR] result

Comment: Figured it out anyway. Can you explain these parameters `(1:1,4,BI,TO=ZD,LENGTH=6,10:5,1,15:6,32)`

Comment: `1,4,BI,TO=ZD` means that your input starting from 1 to 4 bytes is Binary and you want to convert it to Zoned Decimal (viewable format) and then `LENGTH=6` tells that you want that ZD to be of length 6. Then `10:5,1` says that from column 10 in output, you want what is present in input at column 5 and 1 byte long. Then `15:6,32` says that, at column 15 of output, you want what is present in input at column 6 with 32 bytes. Glad you got what you wanted.

Comment: How can I remove the leading zeros of a column?

Comment: IF you want to remove leading zeroes from your sortcode then use `1,4,BI,TO=ZD,EDIT=(IIIIIT)`. So, it becomes `(1:1,4,BI,TO=ZD,EDIT=(IIIIIT),10:5,1,15:6,32)`

Comment: Here's my code for another job
  `BUILD=(1:1,4,BI,TO=ZD,LENGTH=6,10:5,4,BI,TO=ZD,LENGTH=8, 
         20:9,4,BI,TO=ZD,EDIT=(IIIIIT),30:13,32) ` and I got syntax error. The format for the third column is 4-byte signed integer. What did I do wrong?

Comment: If it is another requirement, post another question with representative input data and required output. I'll have a look.